# I'm studying the C# constructor and destructor with Unity, but I don't know why it works like this

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm studying C#'s Constructer and destructor with unity component system.
I'm sorry if the English of this question is weird. I used a translator cause I am not good at English.
The log output came out like this.

1. The Constructor log was displayed without pressing the play button. Why?
   [image: Constructor Log(Did not clicked play button)]
2. When I pressed the play button, I saw a log of something being created and immediately disappearing. I didn't write a code to create an object after the game started, where does this phrase run?[image: Game play first log]

**This is my code.**

> **project working structure**
>
> Pressing the space bar brings the pre-made pre-fab to the game world,
> and Prefab has a component that attached to test the constructor and
> destructor.

**CubeFactory.cs** / when Press the space bar, It creates Prefab.
this component was attached to "GameObject" Gameobject

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeFactory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;
    private int pos = 1;
    void Start()
    {   
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Instantiate(obj,new Vector3(pos,0,0),Quaternion.identity);
            pos++;
        }
    }
}
```

**ClassTest.cs** / Component for Testing Constructor and Destructor. It attached Cube prefab.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ClassTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ClassTest(){
        Debug.Log("I was born!");
    }
    ~ClassTest(){
        Debug.Log("I Died x0x");
    }
}
```

This is my project file. (I'm sorry to compress it up. I haven't learned how to use Git yet.)<
https://github.com/Scincy/UnityStudy

Comment: There are no destructors in C#. There is a finalizer. Please don't use finalizers in your code. Never-ever. They are evil and only required for special cases.

Comment: Also using constructor in MonoBehaviours is not a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your ClassTest.cs script to use simpler functions. Never use constructors and finalizers in Unity. What I understood from your logic is that when you press Spacebar, an object is instantiated. The ClassTest.cs is attached to this object. Better use:

```
  void Start()
    {
      Debug.Log("I was born!"); //Will be called when the gameObject is active for the first time
    }
```

Now you also want to know if the gameObject is destroyed, you can do this with another script attached to an always-active gameObject such as:

```
public GameObject cube;

    void Update()
    {
        cube= GameObject.Find("Cube(Clone)"); //Depending on how your object is called
        if(cube == null)
        {
         Debug.Log("Either not created or is destroyed");
        }
     }
```

I have used Update() which is called every frame. You could use a different function that you would like to call from another script only once.

Comment: "Never use constructors and finalizers in Unity." Never use constructors and finalizers on GameObjects. It's perfectly fine (and mandatory in the case of constructors) to use this on other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Ye olde wisdom says that you should only use C# finalizers if your class contains a handle (`IntPtr`) to an object in unmanaged memory. If you're unclear what that means, then you probably don't need to be using finalizers; either way, you should never need to use them in a `UnityEngine.Object`-derived class.

Instead, prefer either of these Unity messages:

```cs
void OnDestroy()
{
  // (1) called when the Object is about to be fully destroyed.
}
void OnDisable()
{
  // (1) called when the Object is disabled in the Scene hierarchy.
  //     OR
  // (2) called right before OnDestroy() would be called.
}
```

These Unity messages are of course available on MonoBehaviours, but also on all ScriptableObjects too! (For the latter, `OnDisable` essentially resolves to the same thing as `OnDestroy` since they are not Scene-bound Objects.)

Similarly, you should also avoid using C# constructors on MonoBehaviours and ScriptableObjects. The messages to prefer instead are:

- `void Awake()`
- `void Start()`
- `void OnEnable()`

Each has its own quirks, so you may want to familiarize yourself with the differences and write some tests.

You can refer to the relevant documentation here: (see section header "Messages")

- [MonoBehaviour docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)
- [ScriptableObject docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html)